# Error de enlace entre archivos html y css

Tags: html, css

Hola buenas yo estaba practicando un poco con html y css y nose porque los atributos de css como que "no me los toma", osea que no estaría haciendo efecto en el archivo
[[image: aqui el archivo html1]

[image: aqui el archivo css]

[image: aqui que vean que no "hace efecto"]

PD: lo probe en otros editores de texto y sigue habiendo el mismo problema, y antes si me funcionaba, ahora nose que paso

Comment: ¿Dónde está el error? ¿Qué se supone deberia aparecer?

Answer (score 1):

Comprobaste que la ruta al archivo css sea correcta? `href=CSS/estilo.css` Segun esto deberias tener el archivo **estilo.css** dentro de una carpeta llamada **CSS** ubicada en la misma carpeta que el archivo html.

Answer (score 1):

Acabo de probar tu código y funciona correctamente, revisa la ruta de tu estilo.css

Ahora mismo tienes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/estilo.css">
```

Esto quiere decir que ese html buscará en el directorio donde se encuentra una carpeta llamada CSS donde dentro se encuentra estilo.css

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo ver creo que el problema esta en el directorio que estas usando de referencia amigo, es decir:

1. el archivo no esta en esa carpeta.
2. el archivo tiene otro nombre.

Si nos permitieras ver tu directorio de archivos podríamos decirte con seguridad el caso. Mucha suerte con tus proyectos!.